# Perl supervisor plackup starman perlbrew

Tags: python, perl, supervisord, plack, starman

I would like to know if there is a Perl tool like supervisord to manage processes.

http://supervisord.org/

I have seen a Perl program called Supervisor, but I don't know if it is as good as the Python one:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Supervisor

I want to be able to start a plack server and have a monitor that restart it if necessary.

I use perlbrew, I thought of making a shell script to start the server and then have a configuration like this:

```
[program:my_app]
directory = /home/username/my_app
user = username
command = /home/username/wmy_app/starman.sh
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_stderr.log
```

Did you used Supervisord for Perl projects with plack, starman and perlbrew.
What do you suggest?

My question is open to understand what would be best for my plack server in production.

Thanks

Comment: http://p3rl.org/Server::Starter http://p3rl.org/Ubic::Service::ServerStarter

Comment: Thank you very much daxim I'll watch it right now.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use supervisor?

Comment: Yes, we use it for a million apps with plackup and mostly starman. If you would ask a non-vague question, I might be able to answer it.

Comment: Thank you very much hobbs for your time. I especially wanted to know if exist similair Perl tools we recommend using, but you tell me that you used on large projects I'll do use supervisor. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want a perl program to handle that?

There is two recent alternatives you may want to look at:

- Gafferd : http://gaffer.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.0/gafferd.html
- Circusd : http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

If your program is a daemon, why don't you use Runit, Upstart or Systemd

Comment: I would know what be best for my plack server in production, thank you very much for your response. I'm going to look circus and supervisor.